Why is Linux device showing on Google's "Your devices" when using Samsung Browser?
My Samsung Galaxy S23 was stolen while in Rome on vacation. I used the Google Account Management / Security / Your devices screen to indicate what devices have connected to my Google account since the theft 10 days ago. I'm seeing a Linux device repeatedly showing up, but I have no Linux devices in my possession.  For example, I see

Where you're signed in
1 session on Linux computer

and

History
2 sessions on Linux computer(s)

I see an entry as follows, marked 'new':

Linux
Rome, Italy
Sep 8
Samsung Browser

I've seen several entries like this over the past few days, and it tends to be associated with the Samsung Browser. In one case, the timestamp seemed to correlate to the time I tried to issue a device lock/wipe using the Samsung tool, so I'm wondering if there is some way that the Samsung Browser (on my Samsung Android tablet) is somehow being recognized as a Linux device. I've been issuing 'Sign out' commands whenever I see this.
I've changed the password on my Samsung account and on my Google account more than once since the theft.
Is it normal to see Linux devices showing up in this manner?

If you use Samsung Browser and log in into google.com then this login activity will be shown in the security relevant activity log as "Login on Linux".
I section "My Devices" this session is shown as

Linux
[the country you are in]
Samsung Browser

The reason for this behavior is the User Agent string used by Samsung Browser:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
This user Agent was used on an Android arm64 device, but it claims to be from an x86_64 device. The same I saw using Chrome web browser on Android.
In the end I found out that this "faked user agent" regarding the OS is used if you enable the "Desktop web site" option. If this option is disabled or set to "Mobile web site" then Samsung Browser and Chrome correctly identify themselves as running on Android und the device model "K" (Android version is always "10" and device model "K" no matter what Android version is installed - see Chromium User-Agent reduction).
User agent string of Samsung Browser showing the website as "Mobile web Site":
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Tested with Samsung Browser 26.0.3.7 on an Android 14 Samsung tablet.

Thanks for the info. In your testing, using chrome, did the access show as coming from Linux? In my testing Chrome and edge seem to be reported as Android or the actual tablet name. Could you possibly tell me where to view this string? I'm stuck traveling at the moment with only my tablet but I'm trying to make sense of these access logs to better understand what kind of trouble I'm in.

@Steerpike I haven't tested Chrome, but the user agent is the same it may also be listed as "Linux". BTW: see my edit, the reason for the browser using the faking OS string in user agent is the mobile/desktop option for the selected web site.

I just tried in chrome, and was not able to get a 'linux' entry in the log, even switching between desktop and mobile. But I was immediately able to get the Linux entry with the Samsung browser. I hate the way Samsung switches between desktop and mobile; there's a button that says 'mobile' which I THINK means you are currently in desktop. Touch it and the icon changes to say desktop, which I THINK means switch to desktop.  The sites I tested with all showed similar info in both modes so very unclear what's going on.  Where can I see this string for Samsung browser?

@Steerpike simply search at Google for "show my user agent". Then Google will display it directly and show you online pages that do the same.

Thanks. Interesting!
chrome, desktop view -
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
chrome, mobile view -
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Samsung, desktop site -
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Samsung, mobile site -
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Sorry, my last comment lost all line breaks and I cannot figure out how to add them on my tablet. There are four sections, two each for chrome, and two each for Samsung browser. You can really see the differences. If a moderator could possibly add the line breaks I'd be most grateful. And if someone knows how to add line breaks using a tablet, I'd be overjoyed!

@Steerpike Just FYI, comments don't support line breaks.

@andrewT - could I add the info as an answer, thereby taking advantage of formating? Seeing the 4 strings in alignment really helps illustrate the differences and how Samsung is unique.

@Steerpike not sure if some user agent strings are sufficient for an answer. Your comment would be easier to read if you would have formatted the user agent strings as code (place them in backticks). That is described in the comment help page that can be shown when you klick the Help link right of the comment edit field.

Here are the strings edited to show only the differences
`chrome, desktop view -  (Linux; Android 10; K) Chrome/128.0.0.0
chrome, mobile view -   (Linux; Android 10; K) Chrome/128.0.0.0
Samsung, desktop site - (X11; Linux x86_64)    SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0
Samsung, mobile site -  (Linux; Android 10; K) SamsungBrowser/26.0 Chrome/122.0.0.0 `
So all four entries contain a 'Linux' reference in the string; but 'samsung, desktop site' alone contains a ref to X11 and also to Linux x86_64.

I guess Samsung does this to better simulate a desktop browser, because if the server sees "Android" in the user agent string (as in case of Chrome), it may still choose to serve the mobile version of the site instead of a desktop one.

@raj If web developers would really do so then this may be a wrong decision, because there are large Android tablets and of course Android TV that most likely also contain the "Android" string in the user agent. For both a mobile web site would be not optimal.

My TV is not Android, but LG webOS :), so I can't check what a browser on Android TV would send, but mine sends (Linux; NetCast; U)  Chrome/87.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36 SmartTV/10.0 Colt/2.0. This one is distinctively different - eg. by presence of NetCast and SmartTV strings - from either desktop or mobile browser.
